# Filtering dynamically with checkboxgroupinput in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

So I have some data that looks like this:

```
lat         long            group
40.75482559 -73.84514618    One
40.75759888 -73.84442902    Two
40.75468826 -73.84588623    One
40.82676315 -73.92416382    One
40.82736206 -73.92511749    Two
40.787167   -73.977325      Two
40.82994843 -73.92955017    Two
40.75819016 -73.844841      One
40.82663345 -73.92651367    Two
```

And I'm trying to dynamically display latlong points by their group.

In my ui.R code, I have:

```
  checkboxGroupInput("group", 
                     label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                     choices = list('One' = 1, 
                                    'Two' = 2) 
                     ))
```

In my server.R code, I have:

```
  filteredData <- reactive({ 
    df <- randomtaxi[randomtaxi$group == "One",] 
    return(df)
  })
```

Which works fine.  But the moment I try to add something like

```
    df <- randomtaxi[randomtaxi$group == input$group,]
```

It crashes.  I've also tried things like:

```
if (input$team == 1){
    df <- filter(df, group == "One")
```

and

```
if (input$team == "One"){
    df <- filter(df, group == "One")
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.  How can I dynamically subset data using CheckboxGroupInput in RShiny?

Comment: `input$group` will be a vector? Try using `%in%` - `randomtaxi[randomtaxi$group %in% input$group,] `

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but it still doesn't work -- in fact, it will work if you just hard code a vector (i.e. `groupz = c("One, "Two")` but for some reason it won't take the dynamic content.  The error message reads: `Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`  Could it be something with the way I've constructed the checkboxGroupInput UI?

Comment: inside your `filteredData <- reactive({` put a `print(input$group)` statement and see what it thinks is in there

Comment: It says "NULL" -- hmmm, wonder if that's my issue.  Any ideas from here?

Comment: even when you select something?

Comment: I take that back -- when I select it gives "1", or "1" "2"

Comment: Your hunch fixed it once I cleaned up -- feel free to put it as an answer and I'll vote it up

Comment: Feel free to *tick* the answer too if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `choices` need to be a vector, not a list

```
checkboxGroupInput("group", 
               label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
               choices = c('One' = 1, 
                           'Two' = 2) 
               ))
```

Then you need to convert the `1` and `2` to `"One"` and `"Two"` respectively so that your filter/subset condition will work.