# Checkboxgroupinput in R Shiny with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, shinydashboard

Love all the help here so far, but having to teach myself R / Shiny, with no one in the office to help, I am unfortunately stuck again!!

I am trying to do checkboxgroups in Shiny. I read quite a bit, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343387/r-shiny-ggplot2-checkboxgroup-to-plot-specific-data), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596286/how-do-you-create-selection-list-based-on-the-column-names-of-a-custom-file-in-s), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480398/adding-map-elements-in-shiny-leaflet-using-a-checkboxgroupinput), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735492/filtering-dynamically-with-checkboxgroupinput-in-rshiny) and [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/checkboxGroupInput.html) already helped, but I am stuck now.

So my data set "ConversionsCompletions" looks now something like this :

```
 date     |   goal1completions | goal
--------------------------------------------
01012016  |         4          | goal1
01012016  |        10          | goal2 
01012016  |         8          | goal3
01012016  |        13          | goal4 
02012016  |         6          | goal1
02012016  |         7          | goal2   
.....
```

ui:

```
                          checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Goal"), 
                                             choices = c("Goal 1" = "goal1",
                                                            "Goal 2" = "goal2", 
                                                            "Goal 3" = "goal3",
                                                            "Goal 4" = "goal4",
                                                            "Goal 5" = "goal5",
                                                            "Goal 6" = "goal6",
                                                            "Goal 7" = "goal7"),
                                             selected = "Goal 1")

 plotlyOutput("Conversionrate1")
```

server:

```
filteredData <- reactive({ 

  filter(ConversionsCompletions[ConversionsCompletions$goal %in% input$checkGroup,])
})


 output$Conversionrate1 <- renderPlotly({
 plot_ly(filteredData(), x = ConversionsCompletions$date, y = ConversionsCompletions$goal1Completions, mode = "lines + markers", hoverinfo = y) 


})
```

There is a graph, but it doesn't change when I switch boxes, or shows more than one line at a time. I know usually you need to add the "add_trace" code for plotly charts, so I am not sure how to do it in this case when sometimes there is one line and sometimes multiple.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Do you want to have a separate line for each "goal" ?

Comment: Ideally... Is that possible?

Comment: I'm working on it :)

Comment: your'e a star :) thanks a ton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To render a graph properly, you have to use `filteredData()` and slightly change syntax.

As the first parameter `data` you should use the filtered dataset and then for `x` and `y` variables the appropriate names with a prefix `~`.

To plot multiple lines you can use another parameter `split`. I had to change `hoverinfo = y` to `hoverinfo = "y"` otherwise it didn't work (I have the newest version of plotly)

```
plot_ly(
      data = filteredData(),  
      x = ~date,
      y = ~goal1completions,
      split = ~goal,
      mode = "lines + markers",
      hoverinfo = "y" # "y" instead of y ... at least in the newest version
    )
```

I also used `setNames` function to make the code for `checkboxGroupInput` shorter.

```
setNames(object = paste0("goal", 1:7), 
         nm = paste0("Goal ", 1:7))
```

You don't need the `dplyr` function `filter` for subsetting - at least in this  in this case.

---

**EDITED:**

I converted the numeric variable `date` into a `date` format:

```
ConversionsCompletions <- read.table("~/Downloads/data", header = T)
d <- as.character(ConversionsCompletions$date)
d <-  paste0(substr(d, 0, 2), "-", substr(d, 3, 4), "-", substr(d, start = 4,          7))
ConversionsCompletions$date <- as.Date(d, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

rm(ui) ; rm(server)

# use example data
ConversionsCompletions <- read.table("~/Downloads/data", header = T)
d <- as.character(ConversionsCompletions$date)
d <-  paste0(substr(d, 0, 2), "-", substr(d, 3, 4), "-", substr(d, start = 4, 7))
ConversionsCompletions$date <- as.Date(d, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Goal"), 
                     setNames(object = paste0("goal", 1:7), 
                              nm = paste0("Goal ", 1:7)),
                     selected = "Goal 1"),
  plotlyOutput("Conversionrate1")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  filteredData <- reactive({ 
    # no need for "filter"
    ConversionsCompletions[ConversionsCompletions$goal %in% input$checkGroup, ]
  })


  output$Conversionrate1 <- renderPlotly({
    # use filteredData() instead of the full dataset
    plot_ly(
      filteredData(),  
      x = ~date,
      y = ~goal1completions,
      split = ~goal,
      mode = "lines + markers",
      hoverinfo = "y" # "y" instead of y ... at least in the newest version
    ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!, really appreciate it! - However, this seems to only work with the new plotly, which unfortunately broke most of my old graphs - since you seem familiar with the difference between new (4.6) and old (3.5) plotly, can you refer me to a resource where I can find what I need to change with my old graphs for them to display properly under the new plotly? Many thanks!

Comment: Ok seems like I found the website has enough info - need to work through all my graphs and implement changes. Thanks again!!! :)